# I have an error PHP (Warning: Undefined array key )

Tags: php, sql

```
  if($_GET['msg']=="inserted"){
     echo '
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            DATA INSERTED
          </div>
          ';
  }
```

I have an error in this part bit I don't know how to solve this.
the error is (Warning: Undefined array key "msg" in C:\xampp2\htdocs\example\index.php on line 4)
please help me, Thank you

Comment: Just try this `if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg']=="inserted") { `

Answer (score 1):

First check if the array key is set:

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg']=="inserted"){
     echo '
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            DATA INSERTED
          </div>
          ';
  }
```